# Google Play Services Statistics

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Was wondering whether Google publish the installed versions of Google Play Services anywhere. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html has some nice stats on installed android versions, but nothing on Google Play Services stats.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official documentation as such from Google regarding the statistics of Google Play Services but there is a lot going in the market. Have a look at the articles below, they will give you a better insight about the popularity of Google Play Services since the time they are released. They are interesting and worth reading!!

http://lifehacker.com/why-google-play-services-are-now-more-important-than-an-975970197

http://www.androidcentral.com/new-google-play-services

http://www.phonearena.com/news/The-Google-Android-fork-Google-Play-services-Android-4.4-and-the-Nexus-Experience_id48229